# Sailsjs file upload get stuck when using PM2 and node > 12

Tags: sails.js, pm2, sails-skipper

I'm facing a weird behaviour, and I don't know where to look anymore.

Here is the bug :
When I upload a file, it starts then stops after 2 or 3 "progress" events. Then nothings happened, it just hang there forever.
The file is written on the disk, and the beginning of the picture is there (like 20%) and that's it.

When does the bug happened :

- if I use PM2 to launch my app, with node vers 14 or 16 or 18 or 20

When does it work normally :

- if i run the app without PM2
- if i run the app with PM2 and node v12
- I I send really small files, like 3KB

What I tried already :

- originally I was using skipper-s3, but realize I have the same behaviour with skipper (save on disk) so the problem is not from there
- I tried to upload the file in amazon without skipper, same behaviour (works without PM2, doesn't work with PM2)
- I'm currently trying to change the body parser, or the body parser options, as it seems it could be related but I'm not sure what to do there.
- I tried to add a "await sleep(3000)" function just after the file upload to let him the time to finish uploading, but it still get stuck
- I had the problem with PM2 4.5, I've updated it to 5.3.0 but I still have the issue

Here is my code where it get stucks (only with PM2)

```
console.log("There is at least one file to upload, start upload");
req.file('attachment').upload({
    // don't allow the total upload size to exceed ~10MB
    maxBytes: 10000000,
    onProgress: function (o) {
        console.log("progess ", o.written);
    }
}, function whenDone(err, uploadedFiles) {

    console.log("upload completed"); //WE NEVER GETS HERE
    console.log(err);
    if (err) {
        return res.serverError(err);
    }
});

// const sleep = ms => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms));
// await sleep(3000);//Wait 3 sec to leave a bit of delay before the retry 

console.log("AFTER FILE upload");
```

And this is an output

```
There is at least one file to upload, start upload
AFTER FILE upload
progess  22770
progess  22771
progess  48962
progess  65372
```

Then it stops here. The example file is 124KB on my disk, and only 64KB has been uploaded.

The uploaded file looks like this :
[image: buggy uploaded file]

Any help, even just an idea in which direction to look would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I Finally understood the problem if this helps anyone :

PM2 was configured to also used AWS X-RAY monitonring. And this was making the request to abort before file was completely uploaded.